# How do I add several .cpp files into a single CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, header, executable

I currently have a project with a template for *one* `CMakeLists.txt` for *one* executable, *one* header and *one* `.cpp` file. I would like for it to have several `.cpp` files, but still have it all compiled and build. How should I make the `CMakeLists.txt` file build and compile all the `.cpp` files, and how can I check if it worked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should I make the CMakeLists file build and compile all the .cpp files

`add_executable` in cmake accepts more than just one argument.
So write your *.cpp* files as follows:

```
add_executable(my_project_executable main.cpp include/helper.cpp ...)
```

Furthermore, using `set` is a basic practice for this, as follows:

```
set(SOURCES main.cpp include/helper.cpp ...)
add_executable(my_project_executable ${SOURCES})
```

> how can I check if it worked?

Well, why don't you just build it to see if it works?

```
# See it build okay.
$ cmake .
$ make
```

Comment: Hey Dean, thanks a lot for the help! I think it worked. 

I'm still having trouble verifying if it is included or if it is not. Could you show me an example of where I could see that it is build? I got a 100% complete build, but just don't know of a way I can verify if the other .cpp files were included.

Comment: @RyanLee When you build, there's a build output. That's where you find most of the information you need. By the way, if you got *a 100% complete build*, that means it worked. C++ compilers will NOT be generous about missing source files, giving you a bunch of *error messages*. So when you have no error messages building your project, you're good to go (at least regarding the building process).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dean!